custom parameterised AuthorizeAttribute with IAuthorizationRequirement and AuthorizationHandler<Requirement> - How?
I want to write something like the following for my controller methods:
[DeviceAccessAuthorisation(Permission="SetDoorProfile")]
public ActionResult SetDoorProfile(string deviceId, int doorProfileId)
{...}

I could probably do this in the custom authoriseattribute, but it feels like setting requirements (class DeviceAccessRequirements:IAuthorizationRequirement) with the Permission and having that be passed to an AuthorizationHandler<DeviceAccessRequirements>
I know I can read the deviceId controller param from HttpRequest.RouteValues, in either the custom AuthoriseAttribute or in the AuthorizationHandler.
I think this would be the ideal architecture.
but I cant figure out how to get the populated requirement to the AuthorizationHandler
Note that I have many permissions, and dont want to create a policy for each, especially as I'm likely to want other parameters.

I ended up using IAuthorizationFilter (implemented this in the custom attribute).
Apparently this is an MBVC specific way, and so is not compatible with SignalR, or probably anything lese that controller endpoints.
